# How to load icon/avatar from uri in Draweritem in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using heinrichreimersoftware'Material drawer library for my project. To load an image from the URL in Drawer item I am using glide.

```
 final ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Looper.prepare();
            try {
                theBitmap = Glide.
                        with(MainActivity.this).
                        load(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()).
                        asBitmap().
                        into(-1,-1).
                        get();
            } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void dummy) {
            if (null != theBitmap) {
                // The full bitmap should be available here
                image.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);
                Log.d(TAG, "Image loaded");
            };
        }
    }.execute();




    drawer.addItem(new DrawerItem()
            .setImage(this,theBitmap )
            .setTextPrimary(getString(R.string.profile))

    );
```

But it's not loading the image, Any help will be appreciated

Comment: see my answer sir I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all no need to use Async Task. Use the below code if you want to set bitmap.

```
// If you want to save bitmap in bitmap object the use this object.
Bitmap theBitmap;

Glide.with(context)
            .load("Your URL")
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap res, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> animation)
                {
                    // assign res(Bitmap object) to your local theBitmap(Bitmap object)
                    theBitmap = res;
                    // Set bitmap to your imageview
                    yourImageView.setImageBitmap(res);
                }
            });
```

If you just directly set the image to your ImageView then follow this.

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("Your URL")
.placeholder(R.drawable.your_stub_image)
.into(yourImageView);
```

Now as you said you want to use it in the Drawer menu in that case you can do something like this.

```
Drawable myDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), theBitmap);
drawer.addItem(new DrawerItem()
                    .setRoundedImage(myDrawable)
                    .setTextPrimary(getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum_short))
                    .setTextSecondary(getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum_long))
);
```

Comment: Okay, as you can see I want to set this bitmap object to drawer item's icon. so how can I use the above code to work with drawer item?

Comment: @neerajgiri When onResourceReady method call you can save your bitmap inside that and using that bitmap you can set it in any of your imageView. Or if you don't want to do that then directly set your drawer item imageview inside onResourceReady it will set your image in your imageview.

Comment: Can please see this URL (https://github.com/heinrichreimer/material-drawer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/heinrichreimersoftware/materialdrawerdemo/MainActivity.java) and I clear my question, see function starting from line number 101. Instead of loading from drawable I need to load an image from the URL. Can you suggest me some idea about how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for image loading in ImageView;

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl())
.into(imageView);
```